# AWS Glue Zeppeline notebook server setup_notebook_server.py is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, apache-zeppelin

I have working environment with roles and permissions all setup. All things were perfectly when we setup Zeppelin notebook server on AWS.

But, today, suddenly, I have created the notebook server again, it was missing setup_notebook_server.py due to which, I was not able to setup notebook server and link it to Development environment. I am kind of stuck. I have checked, I have provided S3FullAccess Role. Same steps I have tried my other AWS Account. There also I faced exactly issue, And there also things were working fine earliar.

So, need help here. Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like a temporary issue:

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2596#issuecomment-694785416

BTW. I am having exactly the same problems as you right now, waiting for them to fix this. A workaround is to use a different AMI with updated awscli, but yeah - that is not convenient at all especially that we are paying for a managed service.

Comment: Got it. It helped a lot. Can you please recommend such AMI which we can use here?

Comment: @ShivkumarAgrawal TBH I did an AMI from a broken machine - first I SSHed there, applied temporary fixes, and then I did an AMI from that. Having that, I just created a new Zeppelin instance via wizard/API call passing the aforementioned AMI.